# Splitting a String that has a particular structure

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a string that goes something like this

```
"330 Daniel T92435"
```

Now I need to obtain the name `"Daniel"`, and I could simply just type

```
string.substring(4,11);
```

But the position where a name (`"Daniel"`) is placed could vary.

And I don't want to use the `split[]` method.

I was thinking if there was a way to make the substring method read data until a whitespace is found.

Comment: What is the exact goal you are after? Do you want to have an array that holds the individual parts with a whitespace separator or just the "Daniel" part?

Comment: Is the string you are looking for always `Daniel`, or can it vary? Can the position vary  as well? Can you have input like this - `330 T92435 Daniel`?

Comment: just "Daniel" part

Comment: You mentioned "But the information where "Daniel" is right now could vary". Does that mean it could occur after T92435 as well - meaning the place where the information is stored - does it vary?

Comment: @DaveCallister if it's always "Daniel", why do you need to extract it from the string?

Answer (score 1):

If input string always has the following string structure `"someSymbols Name someSymbols"` you can use the following regular expression to extract the name:

```
"[^\\s]+\\s+(\\p{Alpha}+)\\s+[^\\s]+"
```

- `\\p{Alpha}` - alphabetic character;
- `\\s` - white space;
- `[^\\s]` - any symbol apart from the white space.

In the code below [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is as object representing the regular expression. In turn, [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) is a special object that is responsible for navigation over the given string and allows discovering the parts of this string that match the pattern.

```
public static String findName(String source) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\s]+\\s+(\\p{Alpha}+)\\s+[^\\s]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
    String result = "no match was found";
    if (matcher.find()) {
        result = matcher.group(1); // group 1 corresponds to the first element enclosed in parentheses (\\p{Alpha}+)
    }
    return result;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findName("330 Daniel T92435"));
}
```

**Output**

```
Daniel
```

Comment: The solution is fine. I just wonder at this point ... if it is always the same pattern you could easily use a split on the whitespaces. All you would need to know is the offset in the array. Even though OP said he does not want to use split for some unknown reason.

Comment: @F.Müller Sure, I would *rather split* the given string. The same degree of flexibility, the same logic behind, but simple. The simple - the better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.indexOf(" ")` function.

```
int start = string.indexOf(" ")+1;
string.substring(start,start + 7);
```

Edit: You can use

```
int start = string.indexOf(" ")+1;
int end = string.indexOf(" ", start+1);
string.substring(start,end >= 0 ? end : string.length());
```

if you want to select the first word and don't know how long it will be.

Comment: Note that `substring(start, ...)` would select the space as well - add 1 if you don't want to include it. Also, note that the second way might fail if there are no following spaces - use `end >= 0 ? end : string.length()` to read to the end of the string in that case.